# How can I resolve this error ? pyicloud.exceptions.PyiCloudAPIResponseException: Authentication required for Account. (421)

Tags: python, icloud

I've been trying to do a quick Python program to clean event before a certain date.

(I have 2FA)

Here is my try code:

```
from pyicloud import PyiCloudService
from pyicloud.exceptions import PyiCloudAPIResponseException
import datetime


# Get login credentials for iCloud account
apple_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com" # My iCloud login
password = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" # The app-specific password
#apple_id = input("Enter your iCloud login: ")
#password = input("Enter your password: ")

# Connect to the iCloud service
api = PyiCloudService(apple_id, password)
api.authenticate()

# Get the calendar data
calendar_service = api.calendar

# The date before which events will be deleted
delete_before = datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 10)

events = calendar_service.events(
    from_dt=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    to_dt=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 31),
)

# Loop through all events
for event in events:
    event_start = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(event['start'])
    if event_start < delete_before:
        # Delete the event
        try:
            calendar_service.delete(event)
        except PyiCloudAPIResponseException as e:
            print(f"Error deleting event: {e}")
```

And here is the error I've been getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXXXX\delete_event_icloud.py", line 22, in <module>
    events = calendar_service.events(
  File "XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyicloud\services\calendar.py", line 64, in events
    self.refresh_client(from_dt, to_dt)
  File "XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyicloud\services\calendar.py", line 57, in refresh_client
    req = self.session.get(self._calendar_refresh_url, params=params)
  File "XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyicloud\base.py", line 131, in request
    return self.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyicloud\base.py", line 133, in request
    self._raise_error(response.status_code, response.reason)
  File "XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyicloud\base.py", line 189, in _raise_error
    raise api_error
pyicloud.exceptions.PyiCloudAPIResponseException: Authentication required for Account. (421)
```

I've tried to change the app-specific password by creating new one,

I've also tried to add:

```
"dsid": self.session.service.data["dsInfo"]["dsid"],
```

to the calendar.py of the pyicloud library, but maybe I did it wrong.

I've tried to use my real password instead of the app-specific.

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud#two-step-and-two-factor-authentication-2sa2fa)?